# Firefox has stopped working

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

I am running my scripts on selenium webdriver and after every 2-3 test case I am getting this pop-up "Firefox stopped working". How should I handle this pop-up?[image]

Comment: Are you using any profile?

Comment: Did you try with other browser?

Comment: Either use firefox portable or try this link - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Comment: Which Firefox and Selenium version? Currently there is an issue with Firefox 38 and Selenium  2.45.x: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/437

Comment: Yes, I am using profile. I am trying to use Chrome browser but it is not working. Is there any tutorial that I can use? What is firefox portable?

Comment: Why are you failing in to do so in Chrome? What code did you write? Can you share so that people can see what's wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when I use Firefox 39 with Selenium 2.45. After that I upgraded to Selenium 2.46 and the issue got resolved.

I think that the problem is the Firefox and Selenium version agreement.
Note: the default setting will make the Firefox update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

*Follow the below steps to disable popup and error reporting. This will help the selenium tests to proceed further.*

Steps to disable Mozilla crash popup

**1.1   Turn Off Error Dialog through Group Policy Editor**

1. Open the Group Policy Editor by typing gpedit.msc into the Start search box or the Run dialog.
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting. Double click on “Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors” in the pane on the right.
   [image]
3. Click on the radio button Enabled and then press OK. 
   [image]
   **1.2   Turn Off Error Dialog via Registry**
4. Open the Registry Editor by typing regedit into the Start search box or the Win+R Run dialog.
5. Navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

3. Double click the DontShowUI entry on the right and change its value to 1, then close the registry editor.
   [image]
   **1.3   Disabling Windows Error Reporting**
4. Go to Control Panel > Action Center > Change Action Center settings (top left) > Problem reporting settings.
   [image]
5. Select “Never check for solutions” and click OK. Ask before checking also works because the dialog won’t appear to ask you.